# dplyr is not recognising column name

Tags: r, dplyr, data-mining, social-media

I am trying to draw the graph on ChannelTitle but the dplyr is not recogninsing the column even if the column is present in the data frame

Code:

```
videos_year %>% count(channelTitle) %>% arrange(desc(n)) %>%
mutate(channelTitle = reorder(channelTitle,n)) %>% head(10)%>%
ggplot(aes(channelTitle,n)) +
geom_col() +
scale_x_discrete() +
coord_flip() +
ggtitle(label = 'Top 10 chennels with most video uploads') +
xlab(label = 'Channel name') +
ylab(label = 'Number of videos') +
labs(fill = 'Ratio to the total video posted')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `%>%` link was missing between the `head` and `ggplot`, thus `ggplot` didn't get the `data` part (It is possible that the `head` was used as diagnostic purpose and then forgot to connect the plot part)

```
videos_year %>% 
   count(channelTitle) %>%
   arrange(desc(n)) %>%
   mutate(channelTitle = reorder(channelTitle,n)) %>%  
  ggplot(aes(channelTitle,n)) +
   geom_col() +
   scale_x_discrete() +
   coord_flip() +
   ggtitle(label = 'Top 10 chennels with most video uploads') +
   xlab(label = 'Channel name') +
   ylab(label = 'Number of videos') +
   labs(fill = 'Ratio to the total video posted')
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is still having the same error. Also updated the code in my question. can you help?

Comment: ```videos_year %>% count(channelTitle) %>% arrange(desc(n)) %>%
mutate(channelTitle = reorder(channelTitle, n)) %>% head(10)````  same error when running this code only.

Comment: @JitendraYadav can you update your post with `dput(head(videos_year, 20))`

Comment: Thanks. Issue resolved by placing dplyr before count function - `dply::count(channelTitle)`

Comment: @JitendraYadav it happens when there are packages loaded with same function names.  `count` is one function that can be found in multiple packages and the package last loaded would have masked the dplyr count